# How to keep changes WooCommerce Store Exporter Deluxe after update

Tags: php, woocommerce, woothemes

How do I add custom fields to this without it being overwritten when the plugin updates?

I am able to export the new custom fields that I need by changing the file woocommerce-store-exporter-deluxe/includes/order.php.

I tried adding the file to my theme to see if that would override it, but it didn't. How can I make the changes I need without them being overwritten on plugin update?

I was able to do it this way for a different WooCommerce plugin, but that plugin had template files that were able to be overrode. [This is how I did it for a previous plugin.](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

WooCommerce Store Exporter Deluxe does not have templates, so I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see my response here :)

https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202323775-How-to-add-custom-fields-to-WooCommerce-Store-Exporter-Deluxe

Comment: Thanks, you helped answer this questions by posting the answer from you and me for an identical questions that was posted by me elsewhere.